# Android - Values not being stored into MySQL database through php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am sending some values through `HTTP Post` to my server from my Android emulator but the values are not being stored. My logcat is showing `response code 200` and displaying the codes of the `php` script as a http response. My database is fine as i am able to insert data in it. Any idea what might be the matter?

main.java

```
public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String deviceId,
        String registrationId) {
    System.out.println(registrationId);
    System.out.println(deviceId);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.21.78.11/storePost.php?");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        // Get the deviceID
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devid", deviceId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid",
                registrationId));
        //HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(client.getParams(), false);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("HTTP Status = "+status);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

storePost.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DeviceID");
$regid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["regid"]);
$devid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["devid"]);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Android(regID, devID) VALUES ('$regid', '$devid')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: are you running on Emulator or device ?

Comment: What do you see when you open: http://10.21.78.11/storePost.php in normal desktop browser?

Comment: I think you fogot this setDoInput( true ); in your code

Comment: @MichałPowaga I would see the codes of the php script. The address is actually false fyi (using another address).

Comment: @Arjun Which part of my code should I add that line to?

Comment: after this line,,,  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.21.78.11/storePost.php?");

Comment: An error would occur for that as I do not have any method, setDoInput();

Comment: @Hend what is your web server? Are you sure it supports PHP scripts? If does you shouldn't see anything, except just blank site (after opening your `storePost.php` site).

Comment: Using Apache httpd. Hmmm, I'm not sure if it's installed but I just did it anyway. Installed the tar.gz from php.net. But it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'd recommend to use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) it is enough to learn and quite easy to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your web server is configured to run php codes. If you go to storePost.php with your desktop browser and you still see the codes displayed in the browser, then it's a configuration issue with your webserver. Until you fix that, the Android code will still be returning php codes as a response.

If you're on a windows platform, you might want to check this out http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/08/25/how-to-install-and-setup-apache-mysql-and-php-in-windows/

or linux https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Even easier, check xampp out www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I was wondering if I would need to install php in order to run .php files? Btw, I'm using red hat. Anyway, I tried installing php but it says no package available.

Comment: Yes you need to install PHP. Try xampp http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: Alright, I've installed xampp already. But now it's showing error mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/storePost.php on line 3